# Make spacing between stackviews

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I'm new to stackviews and have been trying to use it in a collectionViewCell. This works kind off however i would like to make spacing between the label and image and the two labels. Beside this i also want to make spacing between the label and the edges of the collectionViews. How can i achieve this? here is some images of my stackviews

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> i would like to make spacing between the label and image and the two labels

Select the vertical stack view right beneath `ItemCell`, then go to the attributes inspector and change the `spacing` value, as shown below.

[image]

> Beside this i also want to make spacing between the label and the edges of the collectionViews.

You have to use constraints to achieve this.